# Assign value to Knockout observable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a page that populates its fields(dropdowns and textboxes) from the DB when the page loads via VIEWDATA object from controller.

I am using KnockoutJS for data-binding, below is the scenario

**HTML & JS(dropdown)**

```
@if (Filter!= null)
{
    <select  data-bind="options: RsnAdmAct, 
                        value: selectedRsnAdmAct, 
                        optionsCaption:'Choose...', 
                        optionsValue:'RsnAdminActionID', 
                        optionsText:'RsnAdminActionDescp',
                        optionsAfterRender: function()
                        {
                            setOptionRSN(@Filter.RsnForAdminAction);
                        }">
     </select>
}


self.RsnAdmAct = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedRsnAdmAct = ko.observable();
$.getJSON("GetRAA", null, function (data) {
    self.RsnAdmAct(data);
});

self.selectedRsnAdmAct = ko.observable();
self.setOptionRSN = function (x) {//reason for admin action dd
    self.selectedRsnAdmAct(x);
};
```

this does update the drop-down with the assigned value "**X**".

But the same does not assign value for the text-boxes as below

**HTML & JS(textbox)**

```
@if (@Filter != null)
{
    <input placeholder="Downstream"  
           data-bind="value: DownStream,
                      optionsAfterRender:function()              
                      {
                         setOptionDstream(@Filter.DownstreamNumber);
                      }">
 }

 self.DownStream = ko.observable();   
 self.setOptionDstream = function (x) {//down stream number
     self.DownStream(x);
 };
```

Comment: Is there any method to your code indentation?

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand if your asking about the ident styling I dint find any option in the tools to do so

Comment: Indentation is not a question of "options" in "tools". Indentation is something you do manually. It's nice when there is a tool that does it for you, but that does not mean that you may skip it when there is no tool.

Comment: sorry Ill try to make it neat

Comment: @Tomalak, I just submitted a suggested edit. @sss111, if you pull your code into Sublime Text or a similar editor, you can format the indentations to work better with Stack Overflow. Using `Shift + Tab` and `Tab` while highlighting multiple lines of code can help. Keep in mind that code must be indented "4 spaces" to appear as code, and that long lines should be broken to more readable, smaller lines, that don't force text wrapping.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBrown I will make sure I will follow this for my next post

Answer (score 0):

`optionsAfterRender` applies to options; a text input has no options. Setting the value of `DownStream` will set the value of the text box, because that's how the `value` binding works.

Comment: Is there a way that I can send the Downstream value from the FILTER so that I can assign it as above other than using optionsAfterRender

Comment: I don't know how `@Filter` can be used. Can you do something like `self.DownStream = ko.observable(@Filter.DownstreamNumber)` ?

Comment: The @Filter is a viewdata object from controller I want to stick to the same logic as above since the user has the option to change the value after it is assigned

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search for a proper way to do this but below is the way it works and no other alternative worked.I had to move the function which assigns the value to the texbox observable into the options after render attribute of the drop down as below

```
@if (Filter!= null)
{
<select  data-bind="options: RsnAdmAct, 
                    value: selectedRsnAdmAct, 
                    optionsCaption:'Choose...', 
                    optionsValue:'RsnAdminActionID', 
                    optionsText:'RsnAdminActionDescp',
                    optionsAfterRender: function()
                    {
                        setOptionRSN(@Filter.RsnForAdminAction);
                        setOptionDstream(@Filter.DownstreamNumber);
                    }">
 </select>
}
```

This is the only way it worked for me.Thank you for the posts and comments